# Find Matrix Index Position of an element using lamba

Tags: java, matrix, lambda

I have a matrix composed of numbers **ones** and **zeros** and a single digit **nine**. I would like to find the index position of this number but instead of using for loops I would like to use lambdas. Can anyone help me with such question?

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;


public class FindArrayIndex {
    static final int[][] MATRIX = new int[][] {{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,9,0}};
    static final int NINE = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        printMatrix(MATRIX);
        printMatrixIndexPosition(findMatrixIndexPosition(MATRIX, NINE));
    }

    private static void printMatrixIndexPosition(MatrixIndexPosition mip) {
        System.out.println(mip);
    }

    static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        Arrays.stream(matrix).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static MatrixIndexPosition findMatrixIndexPosition(int[][] matrix, int searchNumber){
        final int rows = matrix.length;
        final int columns = matrix[0].length;
        MatrixIndexPosition mip = null;
        outter : for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] == searchNumber) {
                    mip = new MatrixIndexPosition(i, j);
                    break outter;
                }
            }
        }
        return mip;
    }
}

class MatrixIndexPosition {
    int row;
    int column;
    public MatrixIndexPosition(int row, int column){
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("row index: %d \ncol index: %d", row, column);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very convenient as Java streams lack zip with index and int streams can't be flat mapped to objects but something like this should do it:

```
MatrixIndexPosition mip = IntStream.range(0, MATRIX.length)
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, MATRIX[i].length)
            .mapToObj(j -> new MatrixIndexPosition(i, j)))
    .filter(pos -> MATRIX[pos.row][pos.column] == searchNumber)
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: The mapToObj did not recognized the MatrixIndexPosition so I needed to cast it.